# Symfony Form for Hours Of Operation

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

Currently trying to create a form to submit hours of operation. At the moment I achieved a form where the user is able to select the specific day (monday, tuesday, ...) and the opening time (hh:mm) plus the closing time (hh:mm).

My form type looks currently like this:

```
        $builder
            ->add('weekday', EntityType::class, ['label' => 'app.weekday', 'class' => Weekday::class, 'choice_label' => 'name', 'choice_translation_domain' => true])
            ->add('open', TimeType::class, ['label' => 'site.hours.open', 'input' => 'datetime_immutable'])
            ->add('close', TimeType::class, ['label' => 'site.hours.close', 'input' => 'datetime_immutable'])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'app.save']);
```

I've chosen to use an own Entity to save my weekdays, where 1 = monday, 2 = tuesday, ... (id, name).

However this renders a form where the user has to select each day + each times => submit the form and redo again for other days/times.

This is very inconvientent. My ideal solution would be to use a `CollectionType` for each day, where you can add more times to the collection and submit 1 form with all times per week.

Now this is where  I begin to struggle with. I could make another `FormType` where I embed my current one as a collection - boom done. However this still needs the user to select each individual day - which I do not want.

---

So what do I want? A FomType to create a form the following way:

```
Monday    OpenSelect (HH:MM)     CloseSelect (HH:MM)  [remove Button]
          OpenSelect (HH:MM)     CloseSelect (HH:MM)  [remove Button]
          OpenSelect (HH:MM)     CloseSelect (HH:MM)  [remove Button]
          ---------      ADD Button     ------------

Tuesday   OpenSelect (HH:MM)     CloseSelect (HH:MM)  [remove Button]
          ---------      ADD Button     ------------

...
```

I dont want the user to select monday/tuesday etc - they should already be set. Just add new times to the collection for each day.

Please feel free to ask, if something is unclear.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possible solutions:

1) Create the underlying form object with the collection already created

2) Use a [form event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html) (i.e.: `POST_SET_DATA`?) to add programmatically the missing elements (when creating a new one all will miss but when edit some of them could be there) to the collection

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. So what I'd like to do is to create a FormType called eg `HoursType` which contains the fields `open` and `close` mapped to my entity and use this form as collection in a parent formtype eg `OperationHoursType` - no problem with that. However how do I know which one belongs to which weekday? Since the user does not select it anymore I have to define it first. Mabye I am missing something simple here. Thanks for your help =)

Comment: @Syllz you can programmatically create each `OperationHoursType` with the right week day

Comment: thank you, Sadly I do not know how to achieve this correctly. Just create a **unmapped** FormType with fields eg monday, tuesday and make it a collection of `OperationHoursType` and use `POST_SET_DATA` to set the correct `Weekday Entity` on it? Would that work? Thanks again.

Comment: @Syllz Why would you create `mapped => false` field? Just create the object with all the missing days (the object just to make it clear to what I'm suggesting here, you can also do it directly in the form) in the collection as you would have done without symfony or form component.